# How to lock a file, so another application can't delete it?

Tags: .net, winapi, c#-2.0

Third-party application creates a file, which I read. After the full writing of the file, the app deletes it. How can I lock it so it can't be deleted?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the application writing to the file, what causes the app to all of a sudden delete the file? Should the file be deleted?

Comment: why do you need so? Between, isn't it better to copy content to another file or in memory stream so you can utilize even after deleting of original file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it open and nobody will be able to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Check [`LockFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.